# stop onblur function on click of a particular div

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, reactjs, data-structures

I have an input field as follows.

```
<input onFocus={this.showDiv()} onBlur={this.hideDiv()}/>
```

`showDiv()` make a state variable true and the `div` opens and `hideDiv()` does the reverse.
But I want on click on that particular `div`, it should not trigger the `hideDiv` function. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So when exactly do you want to run `hideDiv()`? Because you obviously don't want to run it for `onBlur`

Comment: @MattWay Everytime except the situation when I click on that particular div

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle or something with your attempt?

Comment: You said **div opens** but how? Where is the code for `hideDiv()` function? As @MattWay stated, please post more code or create a fiddle so that we won't be confused.